# Postgresql JSON data truncated with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm developing an application that at a point, having the java code call the postgres stored procedure (which return a string of JSON).

```
create or replace function get_nsx_all() returns text as
$$
begin
    return array_to_json(array_agg("nguoi.nhaSanXuat")) from "nguoi.nhaSanXuat";
end
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The function executes properly and return this in pgAdmin:
[image]

However, when I call the function through JDBC by using this:

```
public static void getAllNSX() throws SQLException
{
    connection = DB.getConnection();

    CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call get_nsx_all() }");

    statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    statement.execute();

    String x  = statement.getString(1);

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I got only this:

[image]

I wonder what did I do wrong and how can I get the full JSON string to my application.

Thanks!

Comment: The main problem with screenshots, is that we cannot see and copy/paste the actual characters, so I have to ask: What is the space look-alike after `sadfs`? First screenshot shows `"sadfs "` (space between `s` and ending `"`), but if that is not a true space (unicode `\u0020`), then it may be something causing the display of the string to fail. Did you try to print the string length, i.e. `x.length()`? Notice how *all* your values have that trailing "space".

Comment: In addition to that, you can `SELECT astring::bytea::text` to get the bytes in hex.

Comment: Hello Andreas, thanks for your comment. As you suggested, I paste the JSON code from pgAdmin here: http://pastebin.com/raw/a1L6K1zy (you can also view the  txt file here on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7v4qn9ql31e7vc/data.txt?dl=0 )and the length I get in intellij in fact 33,600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there is nothing wrong with Postgresql but since I set the the data type of all strings to character(255), which is a fixed-size string with 255 character, all the trailing spaces are 255 minus string length.

Thanks Laurenz, Andreas for the input.